# Compiler version not recognized

Tags: solidity-0.5.x

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?
Compiler version is there.

$ solc --optimize --abi ./contracts/MySmartContract.sol -o build
./contracts/MySmartContract.sol:1:1: Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version! Consider adding “pragma solidity ^0.5.16;”

^
$ cat ./contracts/MySmartContract.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract MySmartContract {
function Hello() public view returns (string memory) {
return “Hello World”;
}
function Greet(string memory str) public view returns (string memory) {
return str;
}
}
```

$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Linux.g++

Comment: What's the file encoding? utf-8, utf-16, or something else..

Comment: The encoding is utf-8.

Comment: I tried the docker version from here https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/installing-solidity.html#binary-packages with a file and it worked as expected (I just have to fix the double quotes around "Hello World").